# How to read greendao schema version in java code from gradle file

Tags: android, version, greendao

How to read greendao schema version specified in gradle build file in Java code ?

greendao {
schemaVersion 1
}

Comment: did u get any solution? I am having same requirement

Comment: @K.Liaqat, we can use DaoMaster.SCHEMA_VERSION. Accepted the answer by Yang.L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use

```
DaoMaster.SCHEMA_VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle.properties

```
greendao_schema_version = 1
```

Replace 1 with the version of your schema

In the module's build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField("int", "SCHEMA_VERSION", greendao_schema_version)
    }
}
greendao {
    schemaVersion Integer.valueOf(greendao_schema_version)
}
```

Rebuild your project. Then in your code you can access the schema version by calling

```
BuildConfig.SCHEMA_VERSION
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

```
helper = YourDaoHelper();
helper.writableDatabase.version; // it is schema version
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this code is the answer @VladDz